# Why notifications are getting fired on location change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, core-location, uilocalnotification

I am trying to monitor significant location changes for my user. So I have subscribed to significant location changes event in the app but I haven't assigned the delegate (place where I have written the code to fire local notifications) to the location manager. I am not getting why the following code is working.

**ViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
         if (nil == locationManager){
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
                [locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
            }

        }

    locationManager.delegate = self;

    if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]){
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }

    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {

        CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

        locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];


    }
       return YES;
}
```

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW16). Apps using those services can be terminated and subsequently relaunched when new location events arrive. Although the app itself is relaunched, location services are not started automatically. And To obtain that data, you must create a new CLLocationManager object and restart the location services that you had running prior to your app’s termination. When you restart those services, the location manager delivers all pending location updates to its delegate.

But in app delegate I haven't assigned any delegate to the new instance of location manager and I am still receiving the notifications.

Comment: Have you implemented `delegate callbacks` in `app delegate`. Is the `ViewController` in whose `viewDidLoad` `locationManager` is created is a `rootViewController` or is it getting instantiated once you launch the app.

Comment: no i haven't implemented delegate callbacks in app delegate, but yes the ViewController is my rootViewController

Comment: Since you are using the `storyboard` to load the `rootViewController`. The `viewDidLoad` is triggered immediately as you launch the app and hence you are getting the delegate callback.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are allocating two different instances of `locationManager`, which are operating in an independent way. You need to change it to this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...

    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        // Notify the app's UI to instantiate your viewController
        // that then re-initialises its own locationManager.
    }

    return YES;
}
```